# What is difference between Unit and ()?

Tags: scala

I thought () was the only instance of Unit in Scala.

When I try to set a function to anonymous func variable, this works:

```
def some(a:Unit):Unit = {
    println("Enigma")
}
val func:Unit => Unit = some
func()
```

But this does not:

```
def some():Unit = {
    println("Enigma")
}
val func:Unit => Unit = some
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty parameter list as in your second example is not the same as Unit which is a value that represents something like null. () doesn't always mean Unit in every context, 
specifically the instance where your dealing with an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your second example is a method without any arguments.

Take a look at the types that results:

```
some: (a: Unit)Unit
some: ()Unit
```

which would be written in a type assignment as

```
Unit => Unit
() => Unit
```

In the second case, the parens are not acting as Unit, but instead are merely the string representation of an argumentless function. `()` is only symbolic as `Unit` in the context of a method. In a type signature you use `Unit`, because `()` is expected to be a function with no arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
def some(): Unit
```

The `()` here is not the instance of Unit, just no argument.

The normal usage of `()` is

```
def some(): Unit = ()
```

But if you enter `Some()` in Scala interpreter, you will get

```
scala> Some()
res0: Some[Unit] = Some(())
```

Well, it's strange, seems that Scala rewrites `Some()` to `Some(())`. Anyway, I will not write code like this, it makes things hard to understand.

Comment: Compiler gives a warning so its not completely strange.